# How to import external js file with functions in AngularJS component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, external

I’m trying to call functions from an external JS file inside my angularjs component. I’m trying to make it completely barebones so not using a server to serve my app. It’s basically 1 angular component and an external js file with functions that I want to call within my angular component.

I was wondering if this was possible and if it is, how so. I was looking at requirejs but haven’t had much luck with that either. Is this an issue with not having served my angular app?

Thank you so much

Comment: check how the library you want to import to angular is exposed and load it accordingly. Probably you will need to use the object your external js exposes

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My problem is that there doesn't seem to be a way to import the object within the angularJS controller

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you're using Angular 2 or greater, you can declare external JavaScript with something like the following:

```
declare var someJSObject
```

You can then just call functions on the external js library from within your component. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I'm using AngularJS (aka 1) so I don't actually have that functionality :/

Comment: Okay so if you're using javascript (rather than typescript) and the external js file is a not angular - then you only need to reference it in the html using the script tag.

If the the external js file is angular then you will also need to inject it into your angular component... I could provide you with an example of this if needed..